# Setting of form's enctype with JavaScript fails in HTML5. Readonly?

Tags: html, file-upload, yui

We had renewed a clients website, where there was a working user's file upload which was realised with YAHOO! connector.

When we changed the Frontend, we switched to HTML5. Now the upload wouldn't work anymore.

I checked and found out that the form did not have the proper enctype (`multipart/form-data`) set, so the file was not uploaded in the post, just the filename.

But it worked in the previous version.

I examined the code of YAHOO! connector (connector-debug.js) and found, that it tries to set the enctype of the form to the appropriate value of `multipart/form-data`, but no file is uploaded (I checked it in 'Net' register of Firefox).

My question:
**Does HTML5 not allow setting of enctype of a form anymore?**

### edit

Not anyone has tried to answer my question. It's written in **BOLD**

---

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/connection.js.html

```
uploadEncoding = 'multipart/form-data'  
// ...  
this._formNode.setAttribute('enctype', uploadEncoding); // Line: 1181
```

Comment: What browsers were you using in your tests?

Comment: I don't know exactly right now. Possibly a Google Chrome about version 20 to 25 on Win7 (64)

Comment: Can you post an example perhaps?

Comment: does *generating* a form (i.e. $("<form enctype=...>").append(body)) help?

Comment: Try document.getElementById('myform').enctype = 'multipart/form-data'

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
this._formNode.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are implementing but as far as from `Yahoo API` we have to check the user agent.

```
if(YAHOO.env.ua.ie){
    // IE does not respect property enctype for HTML forms.
    // Instead it uses the property - "encoding".
    this._formNode.setAttribute('encoding', uploadEncoding);
} else {
    this._formNode.setAttribute('enctype', uploadEncoding);
}
```